# Variable in Script dependent upon user input of Text Field

Tags: javascript, html, forms, text, d3.js

I am trying to update var `zz` below with whatever a user inputs into the text area when he hits submit. The idea is to create a basic word cloud using the words the user submits in the form.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="../lib/d3/d3.js"></script>
<script src="../d3.layout.cloud.js"></script>
<body>
<script>
var fill = d3.scale.category20();
var zz= ["Hello", "world", "normally", "you", "want", "more", "words", "than", "this"];
d3.layout.cloud().size([300, 300])
    .words((zz).map(function(d) {
        return {text: d, size: 10 + Math.random() * 90};
    }))
    .rotate(function() { return ~~(Math.random() * 2) * 90; })
    .font("Impact")
    .fontSize(function(d) { return d.size; })
    .on("end", draw)
    .start();
........
</script>

<div style="text-align: center">
<div id="presets"></div>
<div id="custom-area">
  <p><label for="text">Enter some text.</label>
  <p><textarea id="text"></textarea>
  <button id="zz" type="submit">Go!</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Take the value of the textarea on submit or button click, split it by a space and set that result to `zz`.

Answer (score 0):

When the form submits, or the button is clicked, take the value of the field and [split](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) by spaces:

Based on your example web page, you had a few issues:

- `x` was not defined, I got an error in the console
- I didn't see any element with the id `demo`, per your javascript

[Here's a fiddle that shows a simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/grhrr/).

```
function myFunction(){    
  var zz = document.getElementById("text").value.split(" ");
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = zz;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response - I'm still not quite there.  Would you mind taking a look at this:  http://jingletree.com/d3-cloud-master/examples/simple.html

Comment: Updated answer with a bit more info. If you `console.log(zz)` you'll see that's actually an array, despite how it may appear in the HTML.

Comment: I think I follow what you are saying but still not getting the results.  I updated the page if you are willing to look at it again.  Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Take a look at my example code. You have `innerHTML = x` but there is no variable named `x`. Change that to `zz` and look at how my code is different than yours

Comment: ok - however I am trying to get it to fill in the zz within the existing code (sorry if I'm not stating this properly).  It should update the zz below  

      .words((zz).map(function(d) {
        return {text: d, size: 10 + Math.random() * 90};
      }))

Comment: The variable `zz` is assigned to an array with the values the user typed, split by their spaces. That is what you asked for, what am I missing?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I started with this:  http://jingletree.com/d3-cloud-master/examples/example.html  Then, I tried to add a text box to replace the zz with what the user inputs.  I was hoping it would create the word cloud.

Comment: I see. This is an issue with load order. The text cloud needs to be re/created when the user adds a new word. In that example it's created on page load and further changes of zz won't do anything.

Comment: I follow what you're saying.  As you can probably tell, I'm a novice. Is that something easy to do?  I'll continue to research.  I really appreciate the help you've given me!

Comment: The example passes the `zz` variable to `...words((zz).map(...`, I'd recommend reading the documentation and see what choices you to have to modify/re-send the `zz` variable each time it changes. It's a bit more complicated for beginners because the example isn't just javascript, but the D3 library and its own unique way of doing things.